# Recaptcha 2.0 Joomla 3 - Validation failed - PHP

Tags: php, validations

I use Joomla 3.4.1 and Recaptcha v 2.0.
I can't validate the captcha, i'm sure i've the good PHP code..

This is the code in plugin file, recaptcha.php :

```
function onCheckAnswer($code = null)[...]
   case '2.0':
      // Challenge Not needed in 2.0 but needed for getResponse call
      $challenge = null;
      $response  = $input->get('g-recaptcha-response', '', 'string');
      echo "response :<br>";
      var_dump($response);
      $spam      = ($response == null || strlen($response) == 0);
      echo "spam :<br>";
      var_dump($spam);
  break;
```

PHP code in my controller :

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$return = $dispatcher->trigger('onCheckAnswer');
echo "return :<br>";
var_dump($return[0]);
```

What this return :

> response : string(0) ""
>
> spam : bool(true)
>
> return : bool(false)

I don't understand, someone can help me please ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Did you create a new key to use with v2.0 of reCaptcha? The old keys won't work. Also, in the settings for the captcha plugin (Joomla backend), did you set it to v2.0?

Comment: No, it's not specified anywhere... And yes i set v2.0 in admin ;)

Comment: I try to get new key, but the google admin of recaptcha get me the same keys for my website ;)

Comment: You're going to need to get a new key

Comment: Ok, i've the new keys. But i doesn't work... Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this solved by making sure the following conditions met

1. allow_url_fopen = On in your PHP configuration
2. jQuery is loaded on my page, if it is not loading, your template or some plugin might be suppressing somehow. check with your template developer.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. "allow_url_fopen" is "On" in my PHP configuration and jQuery is loaded by Joomla (included by default). But i still have my problem....

Answer (score 0):

$result = $dispatcher->trigger('onCheckAnswer',$input['recaptcha_response_field']);